# Is it possible to get the column header text in extjs 4?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I've been looking in the Sencha Docs (extjs 4.0) for a way to get the text header of a column.

I know that is possible to set the text header by using the method setText, I was wondering if there is a way to get the text header?

it made sense at the moment to use getText, but there is no such method in Ext.grid.column.Column.

this is how I create my column:

```
var Column1 =  Ext.create('Ext.grid.column.Column',{
        header: 'myheader',
        dataIndex:'somedata'
    });
```

this is how I'm setting the text header:

```
Column1.setText('Name');
```

the answer might be fairly simple, but I'm new to extjs, so I'm still trying to wrap my head around it.

thanks again guys for your time and help.

Comment: First of all there is no 'header' config - it's just 'text'. Second, why exactly do you need to get column header text?

Comment: @sha 'header' works the same as text, I use it usually. Maybe I shouldn't if it's deprecated and not in the docs...

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply: `Column1.text` that gives you the property.

Comment: yeah. that worked, but I guess using Column1.text didn't give me the info I was expecting. thanks anyway

Comment: @fang_dejavu what info were you trying to get?